# MSTR Dossier - How do I link one attribute to another so that when I remove/add one attribute, the other attribute automatically goes with it?

Tags: microstrategy

I am new to MSTR. I created a Dossier that has a multi-option selector which allows the user to add/remove columns (attributes) in the report. Checking the attribute adds it to the dossier, unchecking the attribute removes it from the dossier.

I have four columns:
|State | City | Building | Building Type

I would like the Building and Building Type to be linked together, so that if I check the box in the selector to add the Building column, both the Building and Building Type columns would automatically be added to the report together, and if I uncheck Building, both columns would be removed together.

Below is an amateur mockup of the report to help you visualize what I mean. In the image, the box with the checkboxes is my selector which adds/removes columns to the report. "Building" is checked and therefore, both "Building" and "Building Type" are added to the report. If I were to uncheck "Building", I want both "Building" and "Building Type" to be removed from the report. Notice that "Building Type" is not on the list. This is on purpose because "Building Type" is irrelevant if "Building" is not on the report.

[Dossier Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J7jH.png)

Does anyone have suggestions? I really appreciate the help!